# How can i get the store configarabale stock status in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I want to get the Stock status and stock available in each store individually for configurable products. please help in getting programmatically

Comment: Hi クジェー,Thank you very much and i appreciate your response, I ma very sorry for giving you much trouble, I am getting results but not Total Qty, my need is if i have one configurable product with 4 children simple products, as stock Qty as like Product A = 2 Qty,  Product B = 5 Qty, Product C = 0 Qty, Product D = 0 Qty with Store X. So the Store X Configurable product total stock is 7, it is accumulated Qty of all children of configurable products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get Store collection here:

> Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface

Then used its store id as filter on the product collection and also join the stock database table, since it was not included on the product collection.

You can do like this and modify according to your needed:

```
$allProducts = [];
$stores = [];

$storeManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface::class);
$_productCollectionFactory = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory::class);

foreach($storeManager->getStores() as $storeId => $value)
{
    $stores[$storeId] = $value->getName();
    $storeManager->setCurrentStore($storeId);
    $collection = $_productCollectionFactory->create()
                ->addStoreFilter($storeManager->getStore())
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable::TYPE_CODE)
                ->addAttributeToFilter('status', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
    
    $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
        "cataloginventory_stock_item as stock_item", 
        "stock_item.product_id = e.entity_id", 
        [
            "stock_item.qty as qty",
            "stock_item.is_in_stock as is_in_stock"
        ]
    );

    foreach($collection as $product){
        $allProducts[$storeId][] = [
            'product_id' =>  $product->getId(),
            'sku' =>  $product->getSku(),
            'qty' =>  $product->getQty(),
            'is_in_stock' =>  $product->getIsInStock()
        ];
    }
}

foreach($allProducts as $key => $data){
    echo '<strong>Store Name: '. $stores[$key] .'</strong>';
    echo '<pre>' . print_r($data,true); 
}
```

P.S. I recommend to not use object manager and do inject it to your construct or class.

Result will be:

```
Store Name: Default Store View

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 1
            [sku] => xxxxx
            [qty] => 0
            [is_in_stock] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 2
            [sku] => xxxxx
            [qty] => 0
            [is_in_stock] => 1
        )
)
```

Updated:

```
$allProducts = [];
$stores = [];

$storeManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface::class);
$productCollectionFactory = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory::class);
$productFactory = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory::class);

foreach($storeManager->getStores() as $storeId => $value)
{
    $stores[$storeId] = $value->getName();
    $storeManager->setCurrentStore($storeId);
    $collection = $productCollectionFactory->create()
                ->addStoreFilter($storeManager->getStore())
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable::TYPE_CODE)
                ->addAttributeToFilter('status', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
    
    $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
        "cataloginventory_stock_item as stock_item", 
        "stock_item.product_id = e.entity_id", 
        [
            "stock_item.qty as qty",
            "stock_item.is_in_stock as is_in_stock"
        ]
    );

    foreach($collection as $product){
        $totalQty = 0;
        $usedProducts = $product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProductIds($product);
        foreach ($usedProducts as $id) {
            $simpleProduct = $productFactory->create();
            $simpleProduct->load($id);
            if($simpleProduct->getId()){
                $stockItem = $simpleProduct->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem();
                $totalQty += (int) $stockItem->getQty();
            }
        }

        $allProducts[$storeId][] = [
            'product_id' =>  $product->getId(),
            'sku' =>  $product->getSku(),
            'qty' =>  $totalQty,
            'is_in_stock' =>  $product->getIsInStock() //configurable is in stock only
        ];
    }
}

foreach($allProducts as $key => $data){
    echo '<strong>Store Name: '. $stores[$key] .'</strong>';
    echo '<pre>' . print_r($data,true); 
}
```

You can get children products by:

> $product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProductIds($product);

Then used product model so you can used below to get stock qty make a total on it:

> $simpleProduct->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem()->getQty();

But its better to used one collection or minized using many load to minized also it execution time.

or do a tricks like this:

```
$allProducts = [];
$simpleQty = [];
$stores = [];

$storeManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface::class);
$productCollectionFactory = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory::class);

foreach($storeManager->getStores() as $storeId => $value)
{
    $stores[$storeId] = $value->getName();
    $storeManager->setCurrentStore($storeId);
    $collection = $productCollectionFactory->create()
                ->addStoreFilter($storeManager->getStore())
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('status', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
                ->setOrder('type_id', 'DESC');
    
    $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
        "cataloginventory_stock_item as stock_item", 
        "stock_item.product_id = e.entity_id", 
        [
            "stock_item.qty as qty",
            "stock_item.is_in_stock as is_in_stock"
        ]
    );

    foreach($collection as $product){

        if($product->getTypeId() == \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type::TYPE_SIMPLE){
            $simpleQty[$product->getId()] = $product->getQty();
        }else if($product->getTypeId() == \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable::TYPE_CODE){
            $totalQty = 0;
            $children = [];
            $usedProducts = $product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProductIds($product);
            foreach ($usedProducts as $id) {
                $qty = (int) $simpleQty[$id];
                $totalQty += $qty;
                $children[$id] = $qty;
            }
            $allProducts[$storeId][] = [
                'product_id' =>  $product->getId(),
                'sku' =>  $product->getSku(),
                'children' =>  $children,
                'total_qty' =>  $totalQty,
                'is_in_stock' =>  $product->getIsInStock() //configurable is in stock only
            ];
        }
    }
}

foreach($allProducts as $key => $data){
    echo '<strong>Store Name: '. $stores[$key] .'</strong>';
    echo '<pre>' . print_r($data,true); 
}
```

Comment: Hi クジェー,Thank you very much and i appreciate your response, I ma very sorry for giving you much trouble, I am getting results but not Total Qty, my need is if i have one configurable product with 4 children simple products, as stock Qty as like Product A = 2 Qty, Product B = 5 Qty, Product C = 0 Qty, Product D = 0 Qty with Store X. So the Store X Configurable product total stock is 7, it is accumulated Qty of all children of configurable products.

Comment: Isee so you want to get the total qty of its configurable childrens(simple products). See updated answer.